# PySpark MLLIB Random Forest: prediction always 0

Tags: pyspark, classification, random-forest, apache-spark-mllib

Using `ml`, `Spark 2.0` (Python) and a 1.2 million row dataset, I am trying to create a model that predicts purchase tendency with a `Random Forest Classifier`. However when applying the transformation to the splitted `test` dataset the prediction is always 0.

The dataset looks like:

```
[Row(tier_buyer=u'0', N1=u'1', N2=u'0.72', N3=u'35.0', N4=u'65.81', N5=u'30.67', N6=u'0.0'....
```

`tier_buyer` is the field used as a `label indexer`. The rest of the fields contain numeric data.

### Steps

1.- Load the parquet file, and fill possible null values:

```
parquet = spark.read.parquet('path_to_parquet')
parquet.createOrReplaceTempView("parquet")
dfraw = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM parquet").dropDuplicates()
df = dfraw.na.fill(0)
```

2.- Create features vector:

```
features = VectorAssembler(
                inputCols = ['N1','N2'...],
                outputCol = 'features')
```

3.- Create string indexer:

```
label_indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol = 'tier_buyer', outputCol = 'label')
```

4.- Split the train and test datasets:

```
(train, test) = df.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3])
```

*Resulting train dataset*

[image]

*Resulting Test dataset*

[image]

5.- Define the classifier:

```
classifier = RandomForestClassifier(labelCol = 'label', featuresCol = 'features')
```

6.- Pipeline the stages and fit the train model:

```
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[features, label_indexer, classifier])
model = pipeline.fit(train)
```

7.- Transform the test dataset:

```
predictions = model.transform(test)
```

8.- Output the test result, grouped by prediction:

```
predictions.select("prediction", "label", "features").groupBy("prediction").count().show()
```

[image]

As you can see, the outcome is always 0. I have tried with multiple feature variations in hopes of reducing the noise, also trying from different sources and infering the schema, with no luck and the same results.

### Questions

- Is the current setup, as described above, correct?
- Could the `null` value filling on the original `Dataframe` be source of failure to effectively perform the prediction?
- <strike>In the screenshot shown above it looks like some features are in the form of a `tuple` and other of a `list`, why? I'm guessing this could be a possible source of error.</strike> (They are representation of Dense and Sparse Vectors)

Comment: I have answer a similar question on my personal gist a while ago. You can maybe take a look at it https://gist.github.com/eliasah/8709e6391784be0feb7fe9dd31ae0c0a

Comment: Thank you @eliasah I wil take a look on stratified sampling. Do you know why some of the feature results appear in the form of a tuple and other as a list?

Comment: Those are just representations of Dense and Sparse vectors.

Comment: What about predictions ? Would you care grouping by predictions after training ? I also believe that I have answer one of your question about vector representation. It's not a source of error. One more question also, does your data have duplicates ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your features `[N1, N2, ...]` are strings. You man want to cast all your features as `FloatType()` or something along those lines. It may be prudent to `fillna()` *after* type casting.

Answer (score 0):

Your training dataset is highly imbalanced.

```
Training samples with label 0 = 896389
Training samples with label 1 = 11066
Total training samples        = 907455
```

By predicting that every record has a label 0, your model achieves an accuracy of 98.78%(896389/907455), which as you have noted does not work as it completely fails to identify samples with label =1.

To create a better training dataset which has more balanced distribution of samples across the 2 output labels, you can use 2 approaches..

1. Undersample the majority class, e.g just take 11,000 random samples for label = 0 and 11,000 samples for label = 0
2. Oversample the minority class, create copies of the data with label = 1.

In this case, your minority class samples are only 1.2% of the majority class samples, so simply duplicating the data will lead to its own issues with overfitting. You can consider SMOTE for synthetic minority oversampling.

Answer (score 0):

Highly imbalanced dataset.

Upsample minority class, downsample majority class, or both.

SMOTE can help and [synthetic data](https://github.com/ydataai/ydata-synthetic/) will make it even better.